# docker pgAdmin4 connection refused while connecting local postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect my local postgres database using pgAdmin4 docker container. When I open `http://localhost:5050/` and login after create new server connection I got **`Unable to connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused`** error message.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: db@db.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: odoo
    volumes:
       - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
    pgadmin:
```

[image]

I am finding solution to connect my local postgres databasw with pgadmin4 docker container. I am using **Ubuntu 20.04** os system.

***---- Updated base on @Veikko answer -----------***

Here is my docker-compose file code https://pastebin.com/VmhZwtaL

and here is **postgresql.conf** file https://pastebin.com/R7ifFrGR

and **pg_hba.conf** file https://pastebin.com/yC2zCfBG

Comment: Where is your DB running and what's the address? pgadmin doesn't contain a db process...

Comment: database running in local 5432 port. I want to access my database in pgadmin4.

Comment: Where do you run the DB? on the machine hosting the container or in another container?

Comment: DB running on local system

Answer (score 5):

You can access your host machine from your docker container with dns name `host.docker.internal`. Replace `localhost` in your server connection with this name. The name `localhost` inside your pgAdmin refers to the docker container itself, not to your host machine.

Comment: Yes I did but still I can not connect

Comment: Thanks for updating the questions with OS info. The host.docker.internal is not yet supported in Ubuntu/linux version of Docker. This works for Docker for Mac/Windows from version 18.03. I will post a linux-compatible answer later as a separate answer.

Comment: name does not resolve - error for me...

Answer (score 2):

You can use image `qoomon/docker-host` to access services on your host computer. Add docker-host service to your docker-compose like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  docker-host:
      image: qoomon/docker-host
      cap_add: [ 'NET_ADMIN', 'NET_RAW' ]
      restart: on-failure
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
...
```

After this you should be able to access your host Postgres service with host name docker-host. Replace `localhost` with `docker-host` in your connection string and connection should work.

If problems with connection after this, please make sure you do not have any firewall blocking the traffic, you have proper Docker network setup (see docs) and your postgresql is listening to this address.

Ubuntu/linux version of Docker does not currently support host.docker.internal DNS name that would point containers to the host. That is the easiest way to link to host in Docker for Mac or Windows. I hope we get this also to Linux soon.

More information about docker-host can be found in Github repo: https://github.com/qoomon/docker-host

Comment: Hi @Veikko Thank you for your answer. I have try as per you answer I got this error https://ibb.co/Kqq9X1T  as well as Here is my docker-compose file code https://pastebin.com/VmhZwtaL and here I shared my postgresql.conf contains https://pastebin.com/R7ifFrGR  and  pg_hba.conf file contains https://pastebin.com/yC2zCfBG

Comment: The pgadmin host name in screen capture is the dns name that works only with win/mac (’host.docker.internal’). Please use name ’docker-host’ in pgadmin field ’Host name/address’. It refers to the service name for qoomon:docker-host container specified in docker-compose.yaml.

Comment: can you please clerify what should I enter in Host name/address field?

Comment: Use ’docker-host’ in Host name/address.

Comment: still not work Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "docker-host" (172.29.0.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: Are you able to connect locally from your host to pg with address 172.29.0.2 without Docker? Your pg_hba.conf configuration looks like it allows only localhost  (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

I have some problem before then now I have find the solution.

Just type this command

```
docker exec <container_name> cat /etc/hosts
```

Then it will show this

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.3      607b00c25f29
```

use `172.18.0.3` as you hostname

Hope this can help you.

Comment: happy hear it, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

First call this: `sudo netstat -nplt` to be sure that someone listening on port 5432.
Than call `sudo ip addr` to know IP of your host mashine.
Than try connecting using real IP instead of `localhost`.
I see in your `ip addr` output:

> `3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether 30:10:b3:e4:39:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff inet 192.168.43.190/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0`

So your real IP is 192.168.43.190

Comment: Where is I find real IP. I have done give both command here is output of both command https://pastebin.com/v91294x0 waiting for your reply thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `server` with host name/address `172.17.0.1`
and make sure PostgreSQL is listening (*).

[install_pgadmin4_using_docker](https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/pgadmin4/install_pgadmin4_using_docker.md)

[image: output]

Comment: No it not work like that. I have to connect local postgres database using docker pgAdmin4.

Comment: It works for me, I am using it in Ubuntu 20.04 - PostgreSQL -12 and PgAdmin4.23(Docker).

Comment: thank you for your reply. can you please update here steps which you follow. Thanks

Comment: I have personal documentation in https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/pgadmin4/install_pgadmin4_using_docker.md  &&   https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/PostgreSQL/Install_PostgresQL_in_Ubuntu.md  &&  https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/pgadmin4/Reverse_Proxying_with_ngnix.md

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add to your `pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            trust
```

or

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5
```

to test.

Then if this works you should change the `0.0.0.0/0` netmask to your docker bright netmask. And check it again. Btw. to connect to you localhost (on host) you need to connect to docker bright ip for me it's `172.17.0.1/32`.

**EDIT:**
Second: `postgresql.conf`

uncomment and read what there is written:

```
listen_addresses = '*'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
```

you need to bind to your IP's that are connectable from docker so in my case it should be `172.17.0.1`